# How to make Big Data smarter and more useful through semantic web approach / OWL?

Tags: web, rdf, owl, ontology

I am learning semantic web and trying to implement a program to make Big Data smarter through semantic web approach / OWL.

Would it be possible to assist me with a small sample code to prove this?

The code can in any programming language. The requirement is to get a sample Big Data,  apply a semantic web technique and make Big Data more usable and prove that semantic web / OWL is helping Big Data to be smart.

Comment: Looking for an urgent answer

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm afraid your question is too general to get a precise answer. Please restate it with a more restricted scope.